# How can I check which version of Angular I'm using?

Tags: angularjs, angular

How can I tell which version of Angular I am using?

I have tried:

```
angular --version
angular --v
angular -version
angular -v
```

but get `-bash: angular: command not found`

I know by `yeoman --version` that I am using `0.9.6`

But how do get the angularjs version?

Comment: [Leo's answer (look at angular related lines in package.json)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43879344/479251) works for any version of AngularJS (1) or Angular 2+. [Tony dong's answer (inspect application tag in DOM)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41496134/479251) works fine for any version of Angular 2 or greater. Loliski's one works only for 1 and 2, not for greater versions. The accepted answer (TheHippo) works only for AngularJS (1)

Comment: Does it make any sense having the question tagged angular and angularjs? They are both completely different libraries. It would make much more sense to have one question for each. Then the accepted answer would not have been partially invalidated when the new tag was added.

Answer (score 225, accepted):

**Edit:** When this answer was written, there was only AngularJS 1.x. Look in the answers below for Angular versions >= 2.

AngularJS does not have a command line tool.

You can get the version number from the JavaScript file itself.

Header of the current `angular.js`:

```
/**
 * @license AngularJS v1.0.6
 * (c) 2010-2012 Google, Inc. http://angularjs.org
 * License: MIT
 */
```

Comment: You can write angular.version  , which gives version of angular.

Comment: @AfshinMoazami Doesn't matter. It is in the comment on top of the file. For licensing reasons you should not delete the comment.

Comment: First, when it is minified, it is not easy to search in a huge file for a license. Second, relying on license file/comment is not really a great choice since it may change by a minfier bug.

Comment: The risk of this answer is if there are multiple angular dependencies potentially getting pulled in and being sure which version the browser is actually loading.

Comment: You can display the first few (5 in this case) lines of the file in terminal with:

    `head -5 angular.js`  


to give you just the head section of the file

Comment: What is the location of angular.js file?

Comment: @NishchitDhanani Yes, that's the best approach. It can be run in the developer tools of the browser. This means you can find out the Angular version for a website you're visiting.

Comment: Adding Guillaume's comment to this answer:
angular.version.full holds the full version (e.g. "1.2.16") as a string

Answer (score 320):

For Angular 1 or 2 (but not for Angular 4+) :

you can also open the console on the developer tools of whatever browser you use and type `angular.version` to access the Javascript object that holds angular version.

Very useful when the script is minified with no header comment.

Comment: angular.version.full holds the full version (e.g. "1.2.16") as a string

Comment: Best answer, the accepted one will be impossible if using minified version

Comment: angular.version and angular.version.full do not work in version 4 but the html 'ng-version' is visible.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Answer (score 193):

For Angular 2+, in any modern browser having developper tools (F12) you can inspect the top level application tag.

For Internet Explorer 11 or Edge you can find information here :[image: Angular version Number]

Works for Angular 2+
Chrome browser

[image]

Firefox firebug

[image]

Comment: Im not seeing this element attribute for angular version `1.5.7`

Comment: Thank you, the `angular.version`was not working at my place

Comment: Works for angular 5 as well. In any browser capable of showing the DOM, which means all modern deskto browsers nowadays.

Answer (score 123):

If you are using `angular-cli`, then you can check it easily by typing

```
ng -v
```

or `ng v` in Angular 8, in Terminal or Bash. Note: Run the command within the project directory.

You should get something like this:

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.24
node: 7.4.0
os: darwin x64
@angular/common: 2.4.3
@angular/compiler: 2.4.3
@angular/core: 2.4.3
@angular/forms: 2.4.3
@angular/http: 2.4.3
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.3
@angular/router: 3.4.3
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.3
```

Comment: Ah, I was stuck on this. If I type 'ng -v' in a non-project folder it just gives the AngularCLI version only -  I thought it would give all info. But typing it from withing a cli created project folder gives all the details of what Angular versions that folder is using

Comment: angular --version instead in Angular 7.0.2.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you use NVM and are not seeing packages that you know you have installed, you may have installed them under a different version of Node. One option is to migrate from a prior version to your current version. See more details at https://github.com/creationix/nvm#migrating-global-packages-while-installing.

Comment: ng v in Angular 8

Answer (score 80):

In the browser's developer console (press F12 to open it), you can type the following,

```
angular.version.full
```

it will give you the full version, e.g. (depending on your current version). [It actually gets the `full` property of `angular.version` object.]

```
"1.4.3"
```

So, to see the full object, if you type

```
angular.version
```

It will give you the full version object containing version information like full, major, minor and also the codeName, e.g.

```
Object {full: "1.4.3", major: 1, minor: 4, dot: 3, codeName: "foam-acceleration"}
```

Comment: With this command you can find out the Angular version for any website you're visiting, as long as it uses the framework.

Answer (score 44):

You could also check your *package.json*:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
  }
```

(The caret `^` will update you to the most recent major version (the first number).
`^4.3.0` will match any `4.x.x` release including `4.4.0`, but will hold off on `5.0.0`.
The tilde `~` matches the most recent minor version (the middle number). 
`~4.3.0` will match all `4.3.x` versions, but will miss `4.4.0`.)

Comment: Handy if your Angular application is not started yet ! But works only if you have the source code, of course. For an online remote application, see [Tony Dong's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41496134/479251), inspecting the main angular tag in the DOM seems to work for any Angular2+ version.

Answer (score 26):

Now it is ng -v

If you are useing angular cli then you can check useing

`ng --version`

Now it is ng -v

Or you can also check in

pakage.json file

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.3.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
```

Answer (score 24):

> There are many way, you check angular version Just pent the comand
>   prompt(for windows) and type

```
1. ng version
2. ng v
3. ng -v
```

[image: check the angular version using comand line]

```
4. You can pakage.json file
```

[image: check the angular version on pakage.json file]

```
5.You can check in browser by presing F12 then goto elements tab
```

[image: check the angular version on your browser]

Full understanding of subversion about(x.x.x) please see angular documentation [angularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/object/angular.version) and [angular 2+](https://angular.io/api/core/Version)

Comment: ng -v is not working in latest angular version (I checked for angular 8)

Answer (score 16):

Another way would be to import [`VERSION`](https://angular.io/api/core/Version) constant from `@angular/core` and then dumping to console with:

```
console.log(VERSION.full); //5.2.11
```

Works in:

- Angular 8 [See docs](https://angular.io/api/core/Version)
- Angular 7 [See docs](https://v7.angular.io/api/core/Version)
- Angular 6 [See docs](https://v6.angular.io/api/core/Version).
- Angular 5 [See docs](https://v5.angular.io/api/core/Version)
- Angular 4 [See docs](https://v4.angular.io/api/core/Version)

Not sure about Angular 2 and 3. (if someone could test that; pages are not available)

---

For AngularJS 1.x use [`angular.version`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/object/angular.version):

```
console.log(angular.version); //1.7.4
```

Answer (score 14):

**To Angular 4, many of the options no longer work. Update July 2017** Two posibilities:

> 1) The simplest one is to open the package.json of our project
>   and to check the versions used, among them the one of Angular.

[image]

> 2) After executing ng serve, we open the inspector of elements of the
>   explorer that we use and we can observe the version as in the
>   following image.

[image]

Comment: So which from all the lines says which version of Angular it is?

Comment: @powder366 `@angular/core` and the siblings (here it means that this is Angular 4, latest update due to the `^` in front)

Answer (score 11):

Just Run `ng v` in command

You will get result like

```
Angular CLI: 7.3.9
Node: 12.11.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.2.15
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, f
... language-service, platform-browser, pla
... router

Package                           Version
-------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.13.9
@angular-devkit/core              7.3.9
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.3.9
@angular/cli                      7.3.9
@ngtools/webpack                  7.3.9
@schematics/angular               8.0.0
@schematics/update                0.13.9
rxjs                              6.5.3
typescript                        3.1.6
webpack                           4.29.0
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are using `angular-cli`, simply use command:

```
ng v
```

Answer (score 8):

> For Angular 1 or 2 (but not for Angular 4+):

You can also open the **console** and go to the element tab on the developer tools of whatever browser you use.

***Or***

Type angular.version to access the Javascript object that holds angular version.

> For Angular 4+ There is are the number of ways as listed below :

Write below code in the command prompt/or in the terminal in the VS Code.(up to 3)

> 1. ng version or ng --version (Find the image for the reference)
> 2. ng v
> 3. ng -v

In the terminal you can find the angular version as shown in the attached image :
[image]

> 4. You can also open the **console** and go to the element tab on the developer tools of whatever browser you use. As displayed in the below image :

[image]

> 5. Find the package.json file, You will find all the installed dependencies and their version.

Answer (score 6):

**Attention**: The following ***only*** checks the **Angular-CLI version!!!:**

Both commands work:

```
ng -v
```

or

```
ng v
```

[image]

Comment: That is the version of "Angular CLI", not the version of "Angular".

Comment: angular cli 7 has command "ng version", which includes angular version

Answer (score 6):

For angular 4+ use,

- ng version
- ng v

Please note ng -v option does not work in Angular 7+.

Answer (score 5):

### For AngularJS - Use `angular.version`

```js
console.log(angular.version);
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS API Reference - `angular.version`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/object/angular.version)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using VS Code editor .

Go to Explorer panel on left side -> find package.json & open it -> under dependencies find @angular/core.

This is your angular version as core is the main feature

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways:

1. You may verify it from your *package.json* file
2. You use the following command:

> ng --version

The command above will result in the following output:

> Angular CLI: 7.0.3
>
> Node: 9.4.0
>
> OS: darwin x64
>
> Angular: 7.0.1
>
> ... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
>
> ... http, language-service, platform-browser
>
> ... platform-browser-dynamic, router
>
> Package                           Version
>
> ---
>
> @angular-devkit/architect         0.10.3
>
> @angular-devkit/build-angular     0.10.3
>
> @angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.10.3
>
> @angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.10.3
>
> @angular-devkit/core              7.0.3
>
> @angular-devkit/schematics        7.0.3
>
> @angular/cli                      7.0.3
>
> @ngtools/webpack                  7.0.3
>
> @schematics/angular               7.0.3
>
> @schematics/update                0.10.3
>
> rxjs                              6.3.3
>
> typescript                        3.1.4
>
> webpack                           4.19.1

So, the version of Angular, Angular CLI, Node and many other packages can be verified from here.

Answer (score 2):

On your project folder, open the command terminal and type

```
ng -v
```

it will give you a list of items, in that you will be able to see the angular version. See the screenshot.

[image: version details]

Comment: Angular CLI: 1.7.3
Node: 8.9.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...
not showing as per screen shot

Answer (score 2):

version after angular 2 you can use from terminal,

```
ng -v



    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/

Angular CLI: 1.7.3
Node: 9.3.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 5.2.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.7.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.11.0
mohideen@root:~/apps/UI$
```

Answer (score 2):

**For Angular 2+**

> Inspect Element (Ctrl + Shift + I)
>
> goTo Elements section and scroll to `<app-root>` tag (refer picture below)

[image: inspectElement]

Answer (score 1):

just go to your angular project directory via terminal and `ng -v` give all information like this

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 8.11.1
OS: linux x64
Angular: 5.2.11
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.7.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.11.0
```

If you check `ng-v` outside angular project directoty then it will show only angular-cli version.

Comment: yes, if you want to see the Angular version, you have to go inside a project folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check it by inspecting the elements on the page:

1. press F12 to open Browser's developer tools.
2. Inspect an Element.
3. Expand Body
4. You will see the version of Angular, like the following:

> **ng-version="4.3.6"**

Answer (score 1):

[image]In the new version of angular cli the [ng -v] will not work.yoy have to type [ng version].

Answer (score 1):

For angular JS you can find it on angular-animate.js file as below:

/**
 * @license AngularJS v1.4.8
 * (c) 2010-2015 Google, Inc. http://angularjs.org
 * License: MIT
 */

Answer (score 0):

**It will be Here..**

> ../project_name/bower_components/angular/angular.js

```
/**
 * @license AngularJS v1.0.6
 * (c) 2010-2012 Google, Inc. http://angularjs.org
 * License: MIT
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just type `ng version`
thats it

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple,
you can see in `package.json` file

Answer (score 0):

Same like above answer, you can check in browser by inspecting element, if it is AngularJS we can see something like below.

The ng-app directive tells AngularJS that this is the root element of the AngularJS application.

All AngularJS applications must have a root element.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. ng --version (For checking Installed Angular Version in system)

2. npm --version (For checking Installed NPM Version in system) 

3. node --version (For checking Installed Node Version in system)
```