# Testing ngResource with httpbackend - Possibly unhandled rejection error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mocha.js, karma-runner, angularjs-ngmock

#### Problem

I am attempting to test a the following controller using Karma, Mocha, Chai, PhantomJS

**IndexCtrl.js** (simplified)

```
app.controller('IndexCtrl', ['$scope', '$resource', function($scope, $resource) {
  var methods = {
      get:{
          method:'GET'
      }
  };

  var Users = $resource('/api/v1/search/:search', {},methods);

  $scope.testResource = function(){
      Users.get({search: 'TEST'}, function(result){
        $scope.someTestValue = true;
      }, function(){
        console.log("hello world");
      });       
  };
}]);
```

**index.controller.test.js** (again simplified, I have other non-http tests)

```
describe('Index', function () {

  var ctrl, $httpBackend;
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));
  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $injector){
      $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');

      $scope = $rootScope.$new();
      ctrl = $controller('IndexCtrl', {
          $scope: $scope
      });    
  }));

  describe('Search', function () {
      it('Changing the override should trigger the watcher', function () {
          $httpBackend.expectGET('/.*/', undefined).respond(200, {});
          $scope.testResource();
          $httpBackend.flush();
          expect($scope.someTestValue).to.equal(true);
      });   
  });
});
```

When I run the test, I get the following error. If I comment out the flush line, it does not throw this error, but it does not work properly.

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) Index Search Changing the override should trigger the watcher FAILED
the string "Possibly unhandled rejection: {\"line\":1421,\"sourceURL\":\"node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js\",\"stack\":\"$httpBackend@node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1421:90\\nsendReq@webroot/js/angular.compiled.min.js:4:16511\\nserverRequest@webroot/js/angular.compiled.min.js:4:12080\\nprocessQueue@webroot/js/angular.compiled.min.js:5:14235\\nwebroot/js/angular.compiled.min.js:5:15007\\n$eval@webroot/js/angular.compiled.min.js:5:46097\\n$digest@webroot/js/angular.compiled.min.js:5:43824\\nflush@node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1813:45\\nweb-test/index.controller.test.js:18:22\\ncallFn@node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4447:25\\nrun@node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4439:13\\nrunTest@node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4936:13\\nnode_modules/mocha/mocha.js:5042:19\\nnext@node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4853:16\\nnode_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4863:11\\nnext@node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4787:16\\nnode_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4831:9\\ntimeslice@node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:82:27\"}" was thrown, throw an Error :)
```

***package.json***

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha",
    "web-test": "node ./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start karma.conf.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.5.9",
    "angular-animate": "1.5.9",
    "angular-lazy-image": "^0.3.2",
    "angular-resource": "1.5.9",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.5.9",
    "angular-typewriter": "0.0.15",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.3.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "elasticsearch": "^12.1.3",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "grunt": "*",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "*",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "*",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "*",
    "grunt-html2js": "*",
    "grunt-notify": "*",
    "ldapjs": "^1.0.1",
    "request": "^2.79.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.6.0",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-requirejs": "^1.1.0",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "requirejs": "^2.3.2"
  }
}
```

#### Mods Note

This is different from [Angular 1.6.0: "Possibly unhandled rejection" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063947/angular-1-6-0-possibly-unhandled-rejection-error) where the error was not triggered by a flush, and the solution was rolling back to angularjs 1.5.9. I have already tried rolling back to angular 1.5.9, to no avail. So for the love of god if I get another blind "marked as a duplicate"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Angular 1.5.9 to 1.6.0 there seems to be some bug with unhandled rejects, do this in your app config

```
.config(['$qProvider', function ($qProvider) {
    $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
}])
```