# Angular 1.6.1 "Possibly unhandled rejection" when using .finally()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

When I handle a promise with .finally() then I get this "Possibly unhandled rejection" error, so instead of .finally I have to use redundant .then() and .catch() with the same code inside. Is this a bug or there's a correct way to handle this rejection?

```
const deferred = $q.defer();
deferred.promise.finally(() => {});
deferred.reject();
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yqorhLam/).

Comment: Please look in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063947/angular-1-6-0-possibly-unhandled-rejection-error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41281515/possibly-unhandled-rejection-in-angular-1-6

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.6.1/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: @SantoshShinde the question was not about why a different error is reported then the one thats was used to rejecting the promise, which is `undefined` in the given code, but why the OP gets the undhandled rejection warning when using `finally`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `finally` for promises has the same behaviour/intent as the `finally` in *try* blocks.

If you write:

```
try {
  throw new Error('test') // do some stuff
} finally {
  console.log('finally')
}
```

Then the `console.log('finally')` is executed, but after that the code will stop with a:

> Uncaught Error: test

The same is with Promises, you can use `finally` to execute code regardless if the promise is fulfilled or rejected, but you still need to use a `catch` callback to handle the rejection.