# Possibly unhandled rejection: null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower

Changing to angular 1.6.7 causing  error

```
this.socialLogin= function (key) {
var jsonToSend = {
  'access_token': key,
};
return $http.post(Config.apiUrl + '/api/v1/social/', jsonToSend).then(function (response) {
  return response.data;
}, function (response) {
  return $q.reject(response.data);
});
};
```

here the sample code,

```
tried
$qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
```

it is just masking the error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 1.6.0: "Possibly unhandled rejection" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063947/angular-1-6-0-possibly-unhandled-rejection-error)

Comment: I mentioned that I tried already

Comment: Please read that post. This discussion has already been done on that post.