# Angularjs 1.7.9 - Possibly unhandled rejection

Tags: angularjs, unhandled-exception, angularjs-ng-resource

I constantly have this error `Possibly unhandled rejection` even when using
`$promise.then(success, err)` or `$promise.then(success).catch(err)`

What should I do to fix this error.
Thanks

---

this is the code

```
this.User = $injector.get('User');
this.User.get(id).$promise
.then(fn, fn)
```

in the User resource:

```
class UserResource {
    constructor($resource) {
        'ngInject';
        this.$resource = $resource;
    }
    get(id) {
        return this.$resource(apis.user + id).get();
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean it's a warning not an error, right?

Comment: @AluanHaddad It's an error ```console.error```, and it's caught on Sentry as a javascript error.

Comment: @Andrew Hani  [Possibly unhandled rejection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44009080/9744379) this may help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possibly unhandled rejection: {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51831457/possibly-unhandled-rejection)

Comment: A better solution might be to swap out angular promises for Native promises given what the linked answer said. Thanks @VigneshA

Comment: @AluanHaddad Native ES6 promises are not integrated with the AngularJS framework. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc..

Comment: yeah, but it's easy to Monkey patch them in

Comment: @VigneshA The issue with these solutions that it tackles a 1.6 version and mine is 1.7.9, and it suggests to simply hide the error ```$qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);``` which is not ideal.

@AluanHaddad can you explain what do you mean by Monkey Patch in this case?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @georgeawg I did as you suggested in the links but the error still persists!

Comment: To re-open the question, I need code that reproduces the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @georgeawg this is the code

```this.User = $injector.get('User');
this.User.get(id).$promise
.then(fn, fn)```

in the User resource:

```class UserResource {
  constructor($resource) {
    'ngInject';

    this.$resource = $resource;
  }

  get(id) {
    return this.$resource(apis.user + id).get();
  }
}```