# AngularJS 1.7.9 : how to debug "Possibly unhandled rejection: {}"?

Tags: angularjs, debugging, error-handling, angular-ui-router, angular-promise

I am aware of siiar questions, such as [Angularjs 1.7.9 - Possibly unhandled rejection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59601385/angularjs-1-7-9-possibly-unhandled-rejection) and those mentioned in it as duplicates.

However, my code does not use promises (that I am aware of; certainly no `$promise` or `$http`).

I am just knocking up a simple `ui-router` demo for a friend. It is just two views, each with a button that toggles to the other view. It works just fine with AngulrJs 1.5, and breaks with the above error in 1.7.

A simple as it is, it's a bit too much code to post. In case, rather than finding the error in my code, I woudl like a canonical answer to help others who read this question in future :  how to go about denugging this error message?

> Error: transition failed (caused by "Possibly unhandled rejection: {}")
>
> ```
> at r [as $get] (http://localhost/common/js/third_party/ui-router_zero_pint_2_point_11/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:11365)  
> at Object.invoke (http://localhost/common/js/third_party/angular-1_point_7_point_9/angular.min.js:45:62)  
> at http://localhost/common/js/third_party/angular-1_point_7_point_9/angular.min.js:46:365  
> at d (http://localhost/common/js/third_party/angular-1_point_7_point_9/angular.min.js:43:495)  
> at e (http://localhost/common/js/third_party/angular-1_point_7_point_9/angular.min.js:44:235)  
> at Object.invoke (http://localhost/common/js/third_party/angular-1_point_7_point_9/angular.min.js:44:320)  
> at http://localhost/common/js/third_party/angular-1_point_7_point_9/angular.min.js:47:18  
> at r (http://localhost/common/js/third_party/angular-1_point_7_point_9/angular.min.js:8:76)  
> at fb (http://localhost/common/js/third_party/angular-1_point_7_point_9/angular.min.js:46:499)  
> at c (http://localhost/common/js/third_party/angular-1_point_7_point_9/angular.min.js:22:57)
> ```

Comment: Thanks. Great tip about not using minified AngaulrJs. I have no idea what "resolvers" are, but will Google. Thanks again (upvote)

Comment: I will ty @wu-lee 's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41281515/possibly-unhandled-rejection-in-angular-1-6)

Comment: I will try that this evening. Thanks. Btw, you are extremely active  & well upvoted on AnguaraJs questions. If that doesn't fix it, I will post a new question with a Plunk & my exact code, and hopefully get an answer to ***my*** problem. But,what about this question? Is there a generic way to debug this?

Comment: Does the code work if you disable the "unhandled rejection" error in the `$qProvider`?

Comment: It does work, just gives those annoying error messages, which I do not wish to blanket suppress for obvious reasons.

Comment: You will get a more informative stack trace if you use `angular.js` instead of `angular.min.js` and `angular-ui-router.js` instead of `angular-ui-router.min.js`. Angular-UI-Router uses promises in its transition module. It looks like you upgraded your version of AngularJS without upgrading the version of Angular-UI-Router. Upgrade your router from V0.2.11 to V0.4.3. It looks like your problem is caused by sloppy Angular-UI-Router code. If they didn't fix the issue by V0.4.3, you can either patch the library or live with the messages.

Comment: The latest version of UI-router (1.0.25) solved the problem. Feel free to post an answer. And, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The latest version of UI-router (1.0.25) solved the problem. Feel free to post an answer.

You will get a more informative stack trace if you use `angular.js` instead of `angular.min.js` and `angular-ui-router.js` instead of `angular-ui-router.min.js`. Angular-UI-Router uses promises in its transition module. It looks like you upgraded your version of AngularJS without upgrading the version of Angular-UI-Router. Upgrade your router from V0.2.11 to V0.4.3. It looks like your problem is caused by sloppy Angular-UI-Router code. If they didn't fix the issue by V0.4.3, you can either patch the library or live with the messages.

### Debugging `"possibly unhandled rejection"`

The stack trace will show the file and the line number from which the error originates. Examine the code and fix the problem. If the error orginates in a third- party library, try upgrading to the latest version or contacting the third-party library vendor.

As a last resort, disable the `"possibly unhandled rejection"` messages:

```
app.config(functon ($qProvider) {
    $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
});
```

This is not recommended as it allows other problems to silently fail.

If one doesn't care about a specific promise failing, add a `.catch` handler:

```
$http(config).then(function(response) {
    //...
}).catch(function(response) {
   //I don't care about errors
   if (debug) console.log(response);
   //Re-throw error response
   throw response;
})
```

### Upgrading AngularJS

When upgrading AngularJS, it is best to upgrade all of the AngularJS modules at the same time. That is when migrating from `angular.js@1.4` to `angular.js@1.5`, at the same time upgrade to  `angular-animate@1.5`, `angular-resource@1.5`, `angular-route.js@1.5`, etc. I have seen unpleasant problems when trying to mix and match versions of AngularJS modules.

When migrating, I recommend upgrading one minor version at a time. For example, upgrade from V1.4 to V1.5 first, fix what breaks, then upgrade to V1.6.

The current version is `1.7.9 pollution-eradication (2019-11-19)`. I recommend using the latest version as the AngularJS team has committed to fixing security bugs only in both V1.2.x and the latest version.
For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating from Previous Versions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration)
- [AngularJS Version Support Status - Long Term Support](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/version-support-status#long-term-support)

### Upgrading Angular-UI-Router

UI-Router for AngularJS has two major versions

> Version `0.4.3` [UI-Router-Legacy](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/tree/legacy)
>
> Version `1.0.25` [UI-Router for AngularJS](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

I recommend upgrading to the latest version of UI-Router-Legacy before migrating to the latest version of UI-Router for AngularJS. There have been major breaking changes between the two and it is best to deal with it incrementally.

For more informaton, see

- [Angular-UI Guide: UI-Router 1.0 Migration](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0)

Answer (score 1):

One way to debug `ui-router` is the following:

From the console inject the `$state` service typing the following:

```
var test = angular.element(document.body).injector().get('$state');
```

Then simulate and perform the transition that causes the problem:

```
test.go('root.details') // use the state url here
```

After that, details of the transition will be printed in console. Into `$$state` object, you may find more details about the failed transition and reasons of failure:
[image]

Comment: It gives me "`Uncaught Error: Could not resolve 'root.details' from state 'search_result'" :-(

Comment: Ok, it seems that you have declared a state with the name `search_result` and then you try to go to the state `root.details`. This is an invalid transition and fails. Change the state `search_result` to  something starting with `root.` for example: `root.results` and try again..

Comment: I don't even have a state named `details` !  Also, I don't inject `$rootscope`, as I consider that to be bad practice. So, how can I be trying to change to `root.details` ?

Comment: Changing "`.state('search_result',`" to "`.state('root.search_result',`"  in my config.js did not help :-(

Comment: I didn't explained well my mistake. If the error occurs while changing state from one view to another(for example if your states are `state1` and `state2`), then go to the first view `state1`, and then from the console execute the above script `test.go('state2')`

Comment: The problem is that I am getting the error before I try to switch state - and my config.js says `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/search");` But, the only change is from AngularJs 1.5 to .7 - it is perfectly fine with 1.5

Comment: The error message says: `Error: transition failed..`, so I assumed that error occurs during a transition. Maybe a transition is happening underneath

Comment: As soon as the system allows, I will award you a bonus for your help. Thank you