# angular.min.js:118 SyntaxError: Illegal continue statement

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I run an old application that was built in 2015. Now I'm using Node.js and running the server, everything is good apart from angularjs. Can Anybody tell me what the error is? As I didn't find any help on the internet.

The error is shown in Google Chrome.

```
SyntaxError: Illegal continue statement
at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:3000/lib/js/angular.min.js:42:56)
at http://localhost:3000/lib/js/angular.min.js:90:32
at Object.link (http://localhost:3000/lib/js/angular-route.min.js:7:274)
at http://localhost:3000/lib/js/angular.min.js:16:71
at la (http://localhost:3000/lib/js/angular.min.js:81:90)
at p (http://localhost:3000/lib/js/angular.min.js:66:341)
at g (http://localhost:3000/lib/js/angular.min.js:58:481)
at http://localhost:3000/lib/js/angular.min.js:58:119
at http://localhost:3000/lib/js/angular.min.js:63:39
at d (http://localhost:3000/lib/js/angular.min.js:59:474) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope" data-ng-animate="1">
```

And Call stack is when I paused on exception in Google Chrome.

> "Error: Failed to execute 'matches' on 'Element': ':visible' is not a
>   valid selector.

↵    at Function.gb.matchesSelector (http://localhost:3000/lib/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2:12236)↵    at Function.m.filter (http://localhost:3000/lib/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2:23357)↵    at w (http://localhost:3000/lib/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2:23168)↵    at m.fn.init.is (http://localhost:3000/lib/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2:23894)↵    at e.(anonymous function).(anonymous function). (http://localhost:3000/lib/js/jquery-ui.min.js:9:18176)↵    at i (http://localhost:3000/lib/js/jquery-ui.min.js:6:12380)"

Package.JSON

```
    {
  "name": "hcphes_web_app",
  "version": "2.2.1",
  "description": "HCPHES Web App",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "applicationinsights": "~0.15.2",
    "async": "~0.9.0",
    "azure-storage": "~0.4.5",
    "body-parser": "~1.12.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.3.0",
    "express": "~4.12.3",
    "mongodb": "2.2.27",
    "nodemailer": "~0.7.1",
    "sendgrid": "~1.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
```

Comment: looks like you have "continue" statement in some inapropriate place, try find it inside the application code and place here

Comment: Also provide what version of Angular you're using.

Comment: @tiblu how can I get version of angular ?

Comment: @happyZZR1400 I dont think so. this application was live for 2 years. Code is fine. but maybe conflict in versions ?  how can I know angular version ?

Comment: @ephemeral normally it's declared at the top of the file, although it might not be as it's minified, have a look at the answers [to this question to find out the version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017699/how-can-i-check-which-version-of-angular-im-using)

Comment: run "angular.version" inside console panel

Comment: @happyZZR1400   its    angular.version  = full ='1.5.8'
  chrome console return that

Comment: @tiblu its 1.5.8

Comment: Using Chrome, open `dev tools`, then go to `Source Panel`, then activate `pause on exception`, then `refresh your browser` and when it pauses due to the exception, look at the `Call Stack Tab` and search where the error happens.

Comment: @Hitmands I  included result in question. can you tell what is error ?

Comment: do you have package.json file in yur project?

Comment: @happyZZR1400 yes I have let me edit question

Comment: `"Error: Failed to execute 'matches' on 'Element': ':visible' is not a valid selector.` seems to be related to another error, you may have more errors... 
the error `SyntaxError: Illegal continue statement` indicates that you're using the `continue` statement wrongly, so, try to search all over the code and check where you are using `continue` (it is usually used inside loops).

Finally, if the app has more than two years, I think you should downgrade the angularjs version to `1.3*`

Comment: looks like you trying to get some html element using ':visible' selector (Which is jquery selector) , btw may be to add jquery to project is good idea

Comment: this is very strange you have no angular node inside you package.json, may be angular is on bower.json?

Comment: @happyZZR1400 yes I got solved .  Can you post as answer please ? and what should I replace return true ?

Comment: @Hitmands thank you brother . I got solved yes it was continue issue. but It is weird instead of jquery why angular lib was error destination . Now I should replace return true instead  ?

Comment: I think it will be very helpfull if you place the fragment of  code where the "continue" statement which causing error , so it will be easy to find better replacement...