# How can I check which version of Angular from browser?

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm trying to buy a angular 5 template online so I just want to confirm for angular version. I have check This question of Angular :-

[How can I check which version of Angular I'm using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017699/how-can-i-check-which-version-of-angular-im-using)

But here in this question app version is shown in below image which is captured from development tool,

```
ng-version is in app tag.
```

[image]

But in the template which I'm trying to purchase has following structure.

```
ng-version is in body tag.
```

[image]

So, Just for reconfirm I just installed Angular 5. 
Here in newly installed application they show,

`ng-version is in app-root.`

[image]

That template has other files like,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js">
```

I have also Tried with `angular.version` but it doesn't work for me.

So, it is confirmed that they are using Angular App not other thing but I'm confused about it's Angular-2,4 or 5.

Is there any otherway we can figure it that which version it's running ?

Comment: [Possible duplicate of following link. Try this Method.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017699/how-can-i-check-which-version-of-angular-im-using)

Comment: @Ahsan9981.  I have already mentioned that I have checked the same question. But my question is totally different .

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Using the ng-version attribute is the correct way to identify the Angular version number.  if you want more confirmation you can execute in console:

```
getAllAngularRootElements();
```

which will show you Angular elements. Or more accurately

```
 getAllAngularRootElements()[0].attributes["ng-version"];
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your reply But It shows getAllAngularRootElements() is not defined in browser's developement console.

Comment: getAllAngularRootElements was implemented back in beta.8 of Angular 2, so it should be known.

Comment: It works in Angular 6, but doesn't work in Angular 7. verify with these websites -> https://www.madewithangular.com/categories/angular/

Comment: Some of those are not Angular applications.  For the ones that are, it is still working.  `ng-version="7.2.8"`

Comment: @naXa As KylerLove suggests, some of the websites featured on that page are not using Angular or AngularJs anymore.

Comment: working for version = "8.2.14"

Comment: Can we disable the angular version which will show via using above code ?

Comment: getAllAngularRootElements()[0].attributes['ng-version'].value

Comment: can confirm that the second code block works for Angular 15

Answer (score 15):

Simplest way is to Hit F12 on browser and in the console drawer *type* -

**angular.version**

and you will see the version.
You can also do **angular.version.full** and this gives something like this **"1.6.6"**

Answer (score 2):

Due to Kyler's Help I figure it out that this template is not built with Angular-5. It's lower than the Angular 2 version beta.8 (I don't know the exact version but but it's not Angular-5).

They are showing that they are made with Angular-5 but it's not Because it show me the error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: getAllAngularRootElements is not defined
```

Because with reference to this git's issue :- https://github.com/rangle/augury/issues/245

I figure it out that `getAllAngularRootElements()` will work with Angular2 version beta.8 and greater. So, it means that it's lower than the Angular 2 version beta.8.

And I have tried this function with my Angular-5 application and that function works.

[image]